If a normed vector space over a normed field $F$ has "arbitrarily small elements", does $F$ have the same property?
Let $V$ be a nonzero normed vector space over a normed field $F$, using the definitions in the links. (Edit: note the definition used for a "normed field" is just a "normed ring" that is a field.) We denote the norm and absolute value on $V,F$ respectively as $||\cdot||,|\cdot|$.
Let $A := \{ ||v|| : v \in V , v\neq0\}$ and $B := \{ |x| : x \in F , x\neq0\}$. These are nonempty sets of positive real numbers. Let $\bar{A},\bar{B}$ denote their closures (in the set of nonnegative reals).
If I'm not mistaken, if $0 \in \bar{B}$ then $0 \in \bar{A}$.
I am wondering about the converse: if $0 \in \bar{A}$, then does $0 \in \bar{B}$ necessarily hold? I'm not sure how to approach proving the affirmative or finding a counterexample; would anyone have a hint, or a suggestion for a source that discusses this?

Perhaps provide the definition of "normed field".

Attempt
Let's take $F$ the field with two elements $0,1$ with the norm $|0|=0, |1|=1$.  It does not have arbitrarily small elements.
Now try the vector space $F^\mathbb N$.  Norm for $V$:
$$
\big\|(a_1,a_2,a_2,\dots)\big\| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|a_k|}{2^k} .
$$
It does have arbitrarily small elements.

Thank you for your help!
